# How to return a column value?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

Can someone help with syntax on returning any specific column of an array in Google Apps Script / JavaScript.

Array

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

2nd row of array...

```
Browser.msgBox(values[1]);
```

```
06 07 08 09 10
```

what's the syntax for returning values of 2nd column?

Are there simpler way without the for loop path, reason being I have a 7k row by 28 column array and trying to mak it more efficient via better call methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the values of second column directly, you will have to aggregate them manually.

Ex:

```
function getColumn(array, column){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
        result.push(array[i][column]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then

```
var column2 = getColumn(myArray, 1)
```

Comment: Are there any simplier way than having to generate a function just for this?

Comment: @user1488934 AFAIK no there is not. Another question which dealt with same requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848004/get-column-from-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 2):

```
Browser.msgBox(values[x][y]);
```

Where `x` is the row, `y` is the column.

<sub>I don't know why you are getting the second row via `2` though. Arrays "zero-indexed". They start with `0`. You should be getting the third row with `2`.</sub>

Comment: He is asking for values if second column, not the value of 2nd column in a row

Comment: my apologies, it should have returned the 3rd row instead. Either case it's so simple to return row of an array but how do you return column of an array?

Comment: @user1488934 you have to run through each row, and retrieve the value for that column.