# Get column in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a JavaScript array:

```
var m = someNumber;
var n = someOtherNumber;
var myArray = // new m x n Array;
```

What's the fastest way to get a column (rather than a row) from the array?

Ex structure:

```
getColumn = function(anArray, columnNumber){
    //if( column number exists in array)
        //get column
    //else
        //return null
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848004/get-column-from-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: Not sure I get what is supposed to be the column and what is supposed to be the row here, I guess you really mean index and value ?

Comment: whoops. fixed using pseudocode above.

Comment: @adeneo, In a 2-dimensional array, the construction is generally `[row][col]` (and `m,n` is common for matrices in mathematics). This is particularly clear when an array is initialized on multiple lines.

Comment: @BrianS - Thanks for the explanation, for me a 2D javascript array is just an array of arrays, and I've never really seen them as rows and columns, but it's probably just my simple mind not getting why it would be easier to treat 2D arrays that way, in javascript that is, in languages that actually have arrays with named keys and more strucure I see the benefit.

Comment: @adeneo, Yes, a 2D array is an array of arrays... but that is, essentially, a matrix (or a table), which has rows and columns. Javascript (among other languages) can even initialize a 2D array in such a way that it _looks_ like a maxtrix: http://jsfiddle.net/Am8Bq/ (Similarly, a 3D array can be visualized as a cuboid, although there's no means to display that in code on a 2D screen!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The “fastest” in terms of “least code” would probably be [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const getColumn = (anArray, columnNumber) =>
    anArray.map(row => row[columnNumber]);
```

```js
const getColumn = (anArray, columnNumber) =>
    anArray.map(row => row[columnNumber]);


const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
];

console.log(getColumn(arr, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick example i think:

```
var column_number = 2;
var column = [];
for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {

    var value = matrix[i][column_number];
    column.push(value);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help for anyone looking for a nice way to do it in ES6

```
 let extractColumn = (arr, column) => arr.map(x=>x[column]);
```

Reference: [GitHub@pauloffborba](https://gist.github.com/eddieajau/5f3e289967de60cf7bf9)