# How to get a column of a 2-dim array in GAS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

How to extract a column of a 2-dim array in GAS? I thought I can do that if I transpose a 2-dim array, but is there an easy way of transposing a 2-dim array in GAS?

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63860734/14265469

Answer (score -1):

```
function getColumnTwo() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheetname');
const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
const col2Values = vs.map(r => r[1]).flat();
```

Comment: Cooper, please, fix typos. Otherwise it won't work and it will confuse beginners.